# Is it wise to repeat models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, Survey, Question and Answer, a Survey has_many Questions which has_many Answers. I'm using these models to store the multiple choice quiz data to be shown to the user. However, when the user takes the quiz, I need some way of getting their answers to the quiz along with the quiz data, for grading and storage.

Would it be wise to make another 3 models, something like UserSurvey, UserQuestion, UserAnswer? Where UserSurvey belongs_to user and the rest of the associations are set up similarly to before. The only difference between these new models and the previous 3 models would be the addition of an attribute like user_answer to the answers table so I know which answer out of the possible 4 the user picked.

Anything wrong with what I'm planning? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Just one model ResponseSet with foreign_keys to survey question and foreing_key to answer that user selected

Comment: I don't have much experience with foreign_keys, all I know is that they aren't supported by all databases (so I never bothered with them). can you expand on this further?

Comment: SO isn't the place to get into a long tutorial on foreign keys. Suffice it to say, one of the major goals of a relational database is to store as few copies of data as possible while maintaining referential integrity (which is the point of foreign keys). There are no databases that you'd be using with Rails that don't support the foreign key concept. You'd be well served by reading up on databases before proceeding further with your Rails project.

Comment: Rails has ORM  support that it is transparent for you. just learn about the orm that you  using are.